# How can I tell what's new in a recently changed thread?

Tags: support

Very often a thread pops up at the top of the page that had been dormant for a long time and just recently got some new content, either an answer or a comment.

How can I quickly determine what's new without having to read through everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two most commonly used views are "newest" and "active". In either view comments do not cause the bumping, it has to be a new question, a new answer or  an edit either to the question or to an answer. In both views the reason for bumping is displayed under the thread's name on the right. The name of the user responsible and their logo are displayed under it. For example:

asked just now

[LOGO] Ono

---

answered 2 minutes ago

[LOGO] Geoffrey Thomas

---

modified 2 hours ago

[LOGO] Luis Henrique

In the thread the same name will appear at the bottom of the corresponding post to the left of the name of the post's author (if different). For example:

Edited 2 hours ago

[LOGO] Luis Henrique

To see what exactly changed click on "Edited 2 hours ago", and it will show the whole edit history in reverse chronological order with changes highlighted in different colors.